# Is this the absolute meta of programming?

Tags: discussion, meta

stackoverflow.com is about programming

programmers.stackexchange.com is discussion about programming so it is meta-programming

this is meta.programmers.stackexchange.com, so it is a discussion about meta programming hence meta-meta-programming

Can we go deeper?

Comment: Your second assumption has three mistakes. Meta-programming is programming the programming. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion site. Pr.SE is about programmers, the job, the tools, the methodologies, the subjective aspect of programming.

Comment: @bigown - Due to the format and the emphasis on subjective questions, I think you could consider this a discussion site. But then, if we begin to argue about whether it's a Q&A or discussion site are we now in a discussion about discussion on a meta-meta-programming site? :)

Comment: @Renesis: This is not a discussion site. Questions must be answerable. If a question need to be discussed it shouldn't be posted on any SE site, including Pr.SE. A meta site is about discussion about the parent site. Last but not least, to understand what is meta: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meta- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming

Comment: @bigown - *discussion* and *answerable* are not mutually exclusive. *"Discussion: consideration of a question in open and usually informal debate. [>](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discussion)"* I guess we are disagreeing on the meaning of the word. If several people are chiming in with different answers, with varying degrees of correctness, to a subjective question, I'd say that's a discussion. In fact, I'd say the SE format is better suited to *productive* discussion than most forums, where even the smallest comment is given the same visual weight as the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your assumptions are incorrect.  Progammers.SE is not about programming, per se, but more about programmers.  Programmers.SE is NOT meta-programming.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is the absolute armpit of programming where nobody laughs at your jokes and everyone is hypercritical of you so much so that they routinely question your very humanity.

Follow the advice of those who came before me and don't ask questions like that.  Furthermore  don't make assumptions based on evidence.

Comment: Gosh, thanks for letting me know.  Guess I won't be visiting here anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

Going deeper is inadvisable, because nobody is sure what happens when you get stuck in [limbo.](http://inception.wikia.com/wiki/Limbo)